# Stats Gather and Validate structure

Tags: oracle11g

Could anybody please explain the below questions.Thanks all in advance !!!

```
begin 
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (
ownname => 'ABC',
tabname => 'EMPLOYEE',
estimate_percent => 100
);
end;
```

1)What is stats gather in oracle ?
2)Whats the purpose of gathering the stats  for a table ?
3)what does estimate_percent mean ?
4)what's the purpose of analyzing a table and what it will do ?

```
analyze  table  ABC.EMPLOYEE  VALIDATE structure;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_stats.htm#CIHBIEII

Answer (score 0):

Gather_Stats as it's name says gathers statistics about the contents of a table.
It is information about the information stored in the tables.
This will help the oracle optimizer later on to determine the best execution plan when executing a query.
The estimate_percent instructs oracle to compute the statistics using only a sample of the existing data in the table in order to speed up the statistics gathering process.
Oracle stores internally information about the  distribution of the data inside a table and/or index. This is than used by the oracle engine to determine the best execution plan for queries regarding the table.
Statistics help Oracle find the best execution plan for the queries.
There are more types of statistics in Oracle, table statistics, index statistics and system statistics. All of them are used by the Oracle optimizer to determine the best execution plan for a query before starting efectively to query the data.